# Confusion with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create 1000 equally spaced points between -10 and 10
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

# calculate the y value for each element of the x vector
y = 2*x**2 - 3*x + 5

# draw a tangent line to parabola at x = -1

a = -7*x + 3

# draw a normal line to parabola at x = -1

b = 1/7*x + 71/7

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(x, a)
ax.plot(x, b)
```

With this code I am trying to plot a parabola, a tangent line to parabola at x = -1 and a line that is normal to the tangent line at x = -1. The parabola and the the tangent line seemingly are plotting correctly, but the normal line always plots parallel to the x axis. What am I doing wrong? First picture(top) is what i get with matplotlib and the second picture is what it should look like (graphing calc.)

[image: This is what it looks like]

[image: This is what it should look like. Using graphing calc. here]

Comment: Try ax.set_aspect(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going wrong here. The first was answered Jody in his comment, the aspect ratio is off. The second problem is the fact that the y-axis value of the parabola goes all the way up to 250. This essentially "flattens" the look of the normal line. You can fix this by cutting of the y-axis using `ax.set_ylim()`. Try the following:

```
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.set_ylim([-5, 20])
```

[image]

This will produce an image with that represents the lines correctly (i.e. you can see the right angles) but the effective aspect ratio of the output figure is not square or of the desired aspect ratio you might want. You can adjust this further by changing the linspace, for instance to `x=np.linspace(-20,20,1000)`.